# Font width and height to match div in js or css

Tags: javascript, css

ANSWER: My answer to how to accomplish this was found here:
[Is it possible to adjust a font's vertical scaling using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839655/is-it-possible-to-adjust-a-fonts-vertical-scaling-using-css)

I have a div which is 
477 width x 171 height, I'm wondering if there's away I can force it to [image]

Using FitText.js on a completely random text "Please don't down vote :)" 
[image]

Adjust my text to fit in the width.  However I would like to un proportionally make it fit.
[image]

To summarize I want to make the text fit the size of a div both height and width.  I realize it might be aesthetically un pleasing since the font is stretched un proportional but for this case I need it.

I've searched not his subject, the answers are very old, '11 and others didn't help for both height and width.

Edit: The question is for BOTH height and width.  Other questions cover only width and proportionally adjusting the font.
Second edit: As also stated above the answers from some of those are from '11 way outdated.

Edit: This covers only width: [CSS : Is it possible to adapt font size to div width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089649/css-is-it-possible-to-adapt-font-size-to-div-width)
This covers responsive text as in proportionally changing font size:
[Pure CSS to make font-size responsive based on dynamic amount of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431411/pure-css-to-make-font-size-responsive-based-on-dynamic-amount-of-characters)
This suggest fittext js  which I posted on here that I'm using and does proportional enlarge: [HTML / CSS - adjust font-size to fill parent height and width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826086/html-css-adjust-font-size-to-fill-parent-height-and-width)
This doesn't give helpful info, [CSS: Scale font-size to fit parent block element height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332964/css-scale-font-size-to-fit-parent-block-element-height)
This covers responsive also.

The question is to adjust to a height and width of the div.
In example make the font in this case 477 width x 171 height.

I haven't been able to dig into it with code because I can't find anything that address doing both height and width.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this library. In the example of the homepage, the text scales and stretches as the div does: https://daybrush.com/moveable/

Comment: Duplicate given only covers width.  On the question I stated that it needs to be width and height.  @Temani Afif

Comment: I am adding more duplicate, shortly you will see 5. As a side note, your question doesn't show any effort of code and can be considered as *too broad* or *asking for external tools*

Comment: I addressed the five references you've given.  None of them address this question of height and width @TemaniAfif Afif